# Android Firebase RecyclerView empty list

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with my `RecyclerView`. In summary, I put a `RecyclerView` connected to my database. Then when I start the activity the list is empty, but if I go back to the last activity and I re-open this activity the list is filled.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_followers);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if(mAuth == null){
        startActivity(new Intent(FollowersActivity.this, HomeScreenActivity.class));
        finishAffinity();
    }

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Seguidores");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Usuarios");
    requestDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("requesting");

    requestList = findViewById(R.id.requestList);
    requestList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    requestList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, requestViewHolder> requestAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, requestViewHolder>(

            Users.class,
            R.layout.users_row_layout,
            requestViewHolder.class,
            requestDB.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())

    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final requestViewHolder viewHolder, Users model, int position) {
            final String other_userId = getRef(position).getKey();

            mDatabase.child(other_userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    String name = dataSnapshot.child("nombre").getValue().toString();
                    String username = dataSnapshot.child("usuario").getValue().toString().substring(1);
                    String fotoPath = dataSnapshot.child("foto").getValue().toString();

                    viewHolder.nameTextView.setText(name);
                    viewHolder.usernameTextView.setText(username);
                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(fotoPath).into(viewHolder.imageView);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
        }
    };

    requestList.setAdapter(requestAdapter);
}

public static class requestViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;
    CircleImageView imageView;
    TextView nameTextView, usernameTextView;

    public requestViewHolder (View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;

        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.circleImageView);
        nameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        usernameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.usernameTextView);
    }
}
```

Then I realized that the problem is with the database, because if I change the root the list is filled in the first time.

Comment: So what is your question now? If you have solved the problem already then please remove the question. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that I have to re-open the activity. I didn't fix it, I thought it was the database

Comment: You need to remove `requestList.setHasFixedSize(true);` from your code.

Comment: Great to know that helped. I am putting this as an answer.

Comment: You are using a very old version of `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` class which has the constructor with 4 argument. Use the latest version. So **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is how you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `requestList.setHasFixedSize(true);` from your code.

You might consider using `setHasFixedSize` in case of your `RecyclerView` items will not be changing their heights during runtime. It has some extra benefits like optimizing the whole recycling of the views. However, you cannot use it for loading dynamic `RecyclerView`.

See the [documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#hasFixedSize()) for better understanding.